# Deal damage to an object while using Raycast

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've created an object and I've added a health bar, but when I want to shoot while using `RayCast` it stops the game. I don't know what can I do more or change. I don't want to create projectiles/balls to shoot.

So this is EnemyHealth assigned to Enemy object:

```cs
public class EnemyHealth : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float maxHealth = 100f;
    public float health;

    void Start()
    {
        health = maxHealth;
    }
    
    public void TakeDamage(float damageAmount)
    {
        health -= damageAmount;
        if(health <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is code where I shoot and take dmg:

```cs
public class HitEnemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Camera cam;
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Ray ray = cam.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f));
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit))
            {
                gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().TakeDamage(10);
            }
        }
    }     
}
```

Component `Enemy` is blank, because I don't know what can I add more.

Comment: Have you used the debugger to see what the state of `gameObject` or `gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>()` is when you get this problem? If the gameobject that gets hit does not have EnemyHealth on it you won't be able to call TakeDamage and will get an error. If you have errorPause turned on in your console this will freeze your game. More information is needed.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean to use `hit.collider.gameObject` instead of the `gameObject` that `HitEnemy` is attached to?

Comment: Have you considered what would happen if here, `gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().TakeDamage(10);` gameobject don't have the `EnemyHealth` component attached?

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to check if the ray is hitting an enemy then take damage
2. without checking you're looking for enemy script in maybe a wall and that's why it's giving an error

```
void Update()
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                Ray ray = cam.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f));
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit))
                {
                    if (hit.collider.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().enabled)
                    {
                        gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().TakeDamage(10);
                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.Log("No Enemy in sight, Ray is touching : " + hit.collider.name);
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to get `EnemyHealth` that's attached to the `gaeObject`. The problem with that is, you're looking for `EnemyHealth` on the (presumably) player controller object, *not* the enemy object.

Let's look at a possible solution:

```cs
void Update ( )
{
    if ( Input.GetMouseButtonDown ( 0 ) )
    {
        // Check to see if a RayCast hits an object.
        if ( Physics.Raycast ( cam.ViewportPointToRay ( new Vector3 ( 0.5f, 0.5f ) ), out var hit, cam.farClipPlane ) )
        {
            // Check to make sure the hit object has an 'EnemyHealth' component.
            if ( hit.transform.TryGetComponent<EnemyHealth> ( out var enemyHealth ) )
            {
                enemyHealth.TakeDamage ( 10 );
            }
        }
    }
}
```